# Fastest algorithm for computing Tate module elements explicitly

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Given an elliptic curve one constructs the Tate module associated to it. What is the fastest known algorithm for computing elements of the Tate module explicitly?

Are there any special classes of elliptic curves E for which more efficient algorithms are known?

Comment: What do you mean by "computing elements" of the Tate module? What ground field? What do you want to do with them afterwards?

Comment: Are you asking how to find explicitly a $\Bbb Z_p$-basis of the Tate module?